# Unix - How to search for exact string in a file

Tags: unix, grep, full-text-search

I am trying to search for all files that contain exactly same id as listed in another file and put the file names in another file. I am using below command to find the files.

```
grep -w -f SearchList.txt INFILES* > matched.txt
```

The ids are listed in SearchList.txt file
example -

```
450462134
747837483
352362362
```

The INFILES files contain data in this format-

> 0120171116 07:37:45:828501**450462134**      000001205 0120171116
>   07:37:45:828501**747837483**      000001205 0120171116
>   07:37:45:828501**352362362**      000001205

The ids which i am looking for are conjoined with other text at the beginning but it has a space at the end.

I tried putting \b at the beginning and end of the search text in SearchList.txt file but i still get incorrect results.

Any leads to right command will be greatly appreciated.

```
-bash-3.2$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.25(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)

-bash-3.2$ grep --version
grep (GNU grep) 2.5.1
```

Comment: [edit] your question to show the expected output given your posted sample input. It's not clear if you're looking for output that is the lines that match the numbers, or the words that match them or just a yes/no if they match or not or something else. Also, format your input and output the same way you formatted your code.

Comment: When your SearhList.txt has entries like `120171116`, `00001205` or `2134`, should they match with the first line or do you have an additional requirement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-w` option to `grep` actually inserts `\b` on both ends of the pattern, you only want it at the end. One option that works is to add `\b` to the patterns with `sed`, e.g.:

```
sed 's/$/\\b/' SearchList.txt
```

As you are only interested in matching filenames you should use the `-l` option with `grep`. Now use this together with `grep` and process substitution:

```
grep -lf <(sed 's/$/\\b/' /path/to/SearchList.txt) INFILES*
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It is very useful.